# Does the Visual Studio SDK provide a way to determine the pin status of an open document?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-sdk

I know of the existence of the Running Document Table and how to access it using the Visual Studio SDK, but I can't seem to find a way to determine UX-specific attributes about the file, like if it's pinned in the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try and get the `IsPinned` state using `GetProperty` and `VsFramePropId`enum.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsframepropid?view=visualstudiosdk-2019

Comment: For anyone else wondering, this example is helpful in getting the IVsWindowFrames needed to access those properties https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/blob/master/ArchivedSamples/WPF_Toolwindow/C%23/WindowList.cs